# Trouble with sending decimal value to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have trouble with sending value from view to controller. When I send a value like `35` it works but when I try to pass `35.00` I have validation message:

> The value '125.50' is not valid for Cena. 
>   When i try give 35,50 i get:
>   The field Cena must be a number.

Here is my view code

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Cena)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cena)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cena)
</div>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Dodaj" />
</p>
```

Model:

```
public partial class Czapki
{
    public Czapki()
    {
        this.Zamowienie = new HashSet<Zamowienie>();
    }

    public int IdCzapki { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Model { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Ilosc { get; set; }
    public decimal Cena { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Rodzaj { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Zamowienie> Zamowienie { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly a culture issue. Have you set the server of the culture to a value that accepts a `.` (dot) as a the decimal separator? And edit your question to show the validation message you get

Comment: Try using [globalization element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=vs.71).aspx) in your Web.config file to change culture and uiCulture to "pl-PL" (if I guessed it right).

Comment: Thank for help i change globalization element like this and it work
 <globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="pl" />